# AmpScript Rss Feed

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, rss

Im trying to pull RSS feed into my email. I want to pull in the `<content:encoded>` as the full description and the image. I added "Set @xml = Replace(@xml1,'content:encoded','contentencoded')". I am using this:

```
   %%[ var @xml, @xml1, @nodes, @rowCount Set @xml = HTTPGet("https://www.tpcc.org/_assets/feeds/blog.php?blogname=daily-bible-reading", false, 0)
Set @xml = Replace(@xml1,'content:encoded','contentencoded') if indexOf(@xml,"<channel>") > 0 then

  set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/rss/channel/item",0)
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)


  if @rowCount > 1 then



    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      var @title
      var @description
      var @link


      set @nodepath = concat("/rss/channel/item[",@i,"]/")

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"))) > 0 then
          set @title = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"))) > 0 then
          set @description = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"))) > 0 then
          set @link = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"),0),1),'Value')
      endif



      ]%%


       <div>
<h3 style="font-family: 'SalesforceSansBold', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#333333; font-size:18px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height:26px;margin: 0 0 5px 0;font-weight:bold;text-align: left" class="font_normal"><a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)=%%" title="%%=v(@title)=%%" style="color:#009ddc; text-decoration:none">%%=v(@title)=%%</a></h1>
<span style="font-family: 'SalesforceSansRegular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#333333; font-size:18px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height:24px;margin: 0 0 20px 0;text-align: left">%%=v(@description)=%%</span><br><br>
<a style="font-family: 'SalesforceSansRegular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#009ddc; font-size:18px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height:24px;margin: 0 0 20px 0;text-align: left" href="%%=redirectto(@link)=%%">Read More...</a><br><br>

</div>
  <hr>
      %%[

    next @i

  else

   outputline(concat("<br>no items found"))

  endif

else

  outputline(concat("<br>no XML found"))

endif

]%%
```

I am getting "no XML found"

This may be a double post.

Comment: Also i am building this in Marketing Cloud, I would only like the first item, how to i pull only one post?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the criteria of your loop to stop at 1 instead of @rowCount. That will pull only the first item.

```
%%[

set @xml = HTTPGet("https://www.tpcc.org/_assets/feeds/blog.php?blogname=daily-bible-reading", false, 0)
set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/rss/channel/item",0)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

if @rowCount > 0 then
    for @i = 1 to 1 do
      var @title, @description, @link

      set @nodepath = concat("/rss/channel/item[",@i,"]/")

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"))) > 0 then
          set @title = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"))) > 0 then
          set @description = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"))) > 0 then
          set @link = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"),0),1),'Value')
      endif
  next @i
endif
]%%

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">  
  <tr><td>@description</td><td>%%=v(@description)=%%</td></tr>
  <tr><td>@i</td><td>%%=v(@i)=%%</td></tr>
  <tr><td>@link</td><td>%%=v(@link)=%%</td></tr>
  <tr><td>@nodepath</td><td>%%=v(@nodepath)=%%</td></tr>
  <tr><td>@nodes</td><td>%%=v(@nodes)=%%</td></tr>
  <tr><td>@rowCount</td><td>%%=v(@rowCount)=%%</td></tr>
  <tr><td>@title</td><td>%%=v(@title)=%%</td></tr>
  <tr><td>@xml</td><td>%%=v(@xml)=%%</td></tr>
</table>
```

Or you can eliminate the loop:

```
%%[

set @xml = HTTPGet("https://www.tpcc.org/_assets/feeds/blog.php?blogname=daily-bible-reading", false, 0)
set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/rss/channel/item",0)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  set @nodepath = concat("/rss/channel/item[1]/")

  if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"))) > 0 then
    set @title = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"),0),1),'Value')
  endif

  if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"))) > 0 then
    set @description = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"),0),1),'Value')
  endif

  if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"))) > 0 then
    set @link = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"),0),1),'Value')
  endif

endif
]%%
```

Comment: Thanks Jake! I added this and it works great! Any idea how i can pull just the first <content:encoded></content:encoded> and <enclosure url=""/> I am pulling in all of it right now. @jake314159